# filling in table from function return sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table such as:

```
PK_ID  LOCATION_ID     LOCATION_TEXT
 1          21           NULL
 2          44           NULL
 3          26           NULL
```

I have a function that returns the `LOCATION_TEXT` from the `LOCATION_ID`. I am trying to do something like:

```
update mytable 
set locationText = (select dbo.fcGetLocationText (LOCATION_ID) from mytable)
```

I am getting the

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

error, which I kind of understand, but I don't know how else to do this... how can I update the `LOCATION_TEXT` column without a cursor or while loop?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the **code samples** button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
UPDATE mytable SET LOCATION_TEXT = dbo.fcGetLocationText(LOCATION_ID);
```

Also why are your column names yelling?

Comment: Possibly a migrated Oracle database? Those tend to have ALL UPPERCASE column names ....

Comment: Duh. Yeah, that works! Thanks.  I think they're yelling because they weren't getting filled properly and they had an inferiority complex and needed attention. Now that they will get updated, they will be happier and can go back to lower case!